# Limit Increase and Decrease Integer Number

Tags: java, android

I am new to java and developing one android application. I am setting margin of layout using java. I do not want give user chance to set minus margin so want allow only from 0 to 100. I am currently doing it like below

```
//increasing margin
    public static int text_bg_margin=0;
    CardConstant.text_bg_margin=CardConstant.text_bg_margin+5;
```

and

```
//decreasing margin
    public static int text_bg_margin=0;
    CardConstant.text_bg_margin=CardConstant.text_bg_margin-5;
```

How can I limit it for increase maximum to 100 and decreasing to minimum 0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if(text_bg_margin<100 && text_bg_margin>0)
   text_bg_margin = text_bg_margin + 5 // or -5
```